# A basis of a Hilbert space is orthonormal iff the sum of the outer products is the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a finite dimensional Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$. We want to show that the set $\{ |\phi_i\rangle \}_{i\in I}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$ if and only if $$\sum_{i\in I} |\phi_i\rangle\langle\phi_i|=I,$$
with $I$ being the identity map in $\mathcal{H}$.

Let $|\psi\rangle\in \mathcal{H}$, then we can write $|\psi\rangle$ as a linear combination of the orthonormal basis. In other words $|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i\in I} c_i |\phi_i\rangle$, with $c_i\in\mathbb{C}$.
This can be rewritten as $\psi = \sum_{i\in I} |\phi_i\rangle \langle\phi_i | \psi\rangle$. Thus we get that $\sum_{i\in I} |\phi_i\rangle \langle\phi_i|=I$.

Now for $\Leftarrow$, when we know that $\sum_{i\in I} |\phi_i\rangle\langle\phi_i|=I$, is where I'm stuck at. I want to first show that if $\{ |\phi_i\rangle \}_{i\in I}$ is linearly independent or has norm 1 that then $\{ |\phi_i\rangle \}_{i\in I}$  is an orthonormal basis, but I don't know where I should start.

Many thanks!

Comment: $I$ is not "the identity matrix in $\mathcal{H}$" (which would make no sense), but the identity *map* on $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: If you identify a separable Hilbert space with $\ell^2$ it makes *some* sense to identify its endomorphisms with infinite matrices whose columns are in $\ell^2$.